# display multiplication table using 2 lists in python

Tags: python

```
arr1= [2,4,6,8,9]

for i in arr1:
    for j in arr1:
        print(i * j, end = '\t')
    print()
```

Unable to represent the row1 and column 1 as the elements of arr1

Please suggest on how to implement the same scenario.. Thanks!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Did you mean `for i in arr1:`, `enumerate()` returns a tuple `(index, value)`.

Comment: Thanks , The output I am trying to get is :

Comment: Hi @Kira, once again, we would like to know what your expected output is?

Comment: Thanks , The output I am trying to get is :                                          
        2 4 6 8 9
2 4 8 12 16 18
4 8 16 24 32 36
6 12 24 36 48 54
8 16 32 48 64 72

Comment: like a multiplication table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
arr1 = [2,4,6,8,9]

# Print the first line
print('\t' + '\t'.join(str(a) for a in arr1))

for i in arr1:
     print(i, end='\t')
     for j in arr1:
         print(i * j, end = '\t')
     print()
```

Output:

```
    2   4   6   8   9
2   4   8   12  16  18
4   8   16  24  32  36
6   12  24  36  48  54
8   16  32  48  64  72
9   18  36  54  72  81
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there,enumerate just extract value and their indexes as tuple

```
for i in arr1:
       for j in arr1:
        print i*j
```

This will do

Comment: @Kira that's because they got the indentation wrong on the last line. But that still wouldn't work because they didn't use enumerate...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for,

```
arr1 = [2,4,6,8,9]
row = 0
print('\t',end='')
for i in enumerate(arr1):
    if row == 0:
        for each in arr1:
            print(each, end='\t')
        print('')
        row = 1
    print(i[1], end='\t')
    for j in enumerate(arr1):
        print(i[1] * j[1], end='\t')
    print(' ')
```

Comment: I'm using python2.7 you can modify it to python3 by adding braces to the print statements

Comment: Thanks , i am unable to represent it as a table, and i would want to display  row1 and column1 must be  arr1

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output you mentioned in the comment, you need something like this.

```
arr = [2,4,6,8,9]
for i in arr:
    print '\t' + str(i),
print ""
for i in arr:
    print (i, end='\t')
    for j in arr:
        print (i*j, end='\t')
    print ""
```

Comment: If this is not what you want, please mention output multiplication table in question itself including spaces and newlines as you want it.

Comment: I have modified the code , as                                              arr = [2,4,6,8,9]
for i in arr:
    print (i,'\t',end = '\t')
print ()
for i in arr:
    print (i,'\t',end = '\t')
    for j in arr:
        print (i*j,'\t',end = '\t')
    print ()

Comment: I need to shift the first row by one space

Comment: Okay, I have edited the answer. Check if this is what you want.